# How to Set Initial Focus in a View?

Tags: sapui5

I have a Detail view in an SAPUI5 app which contains a single input field with ID `"bestellmenge_tu"`. Whenever this view is called, the focus should be on that input field. Unfortunately, when setting the focus on the field in the controller's `onInit` method, the focus will be set but some milliseconds later the UI5 takes it away and transfers it to the "navigation back" button of the detail view.

By putting a `log.trace()` on the input field's `blur` event, I found out that the focus is taken away by a method called `sap.ui.define.NavContainer._afterTransitionCallback` which is called asynchronously (some `window.setTimeout`s between trigger and execution). The function simply looks for the first focusable element in the view and brutally switches the focus on it.

My workaround was to redefine the method `jQuery.fn.firstFocusableDomRef` which is used to find this "first focusable element":

```
// DIESE KANONE FUNKTIONIERT
jQuery.fn.firstFocusableDomRef = (function() {
  var _default = jQuery.fn.firstFocusableDomRef;
  return function() {
    var bestellmenge_tu = document.querySelector("input[id$='bestellmenge_tu-inner']");
    if (bestellmenge_tu &&
        bestellmenge_tu.style.display !="none" &&
        bestellmenge_tu.style.visibility != "hidden") return bestellmenge_tu;
    else return _default.apply(this);
  }
})();
```

But this could be a performance issue (`querySelector` called during DOM transversal at *any* page load from there on), and it is too much coding for the desired effect.

Is there an easier method to achieve this?

I thought of something like

```
<mvc:View controllerName="zrt_dispo.view.Detail"...>
  <Page id="detailPage" initialFocus="bestellmenge_tu">  <!-- ID of the element to carry the focus -->
  </Page>
</mvc:view>
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a working example: [https://embed.plnkr.co/wp6yes/](https://embed.plnkr.co/wp6yes/?show=controller%2FHome.controller.js,preview:%3Finitial-focus%3Dtarget1)

```xml
<App autoFocus="false" xmlns="sap.m"><!-- AND/OR -->
<f:FlexibleColumnLayout autoFocus="false" xmlns:f="sap.f" /><!-- autoFocus in FCL available since 1.76 -->
```

```js
{ // Controller of the target view:
  onInit: function() {
    const myFocusTarget = this.byId("myFocusableControl");
    this.applyInitialFocusTo(myFocusTarget, this.getView());
  },
  applyInitialFocusTo: function(target, navContainerChild) {
    const onAfterShow = () => target && !target.isDestroyed() && target.focus();
    navContainerChild.addEventDelegate({ onAfterShow });
  },
}
```

If you have a `sap.m.NavContainer` (I.e. `sap.m.App` or in `sap.f.FlexibleColumnLayout`), its direct child, aka. *NavContainerChild* which is usually a View, can react to navigation related events. Add a delegate to the [NavContainerChild event `afterShow`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.NavContainerChild#events/afterShow) according to the [API reference of NavContainer](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.NavContainer#controlProperties):

> The `afterShow` event can be used to focus another element, **only if `autoFocus` is set to `false`.**

The event handler is fired after the animation is finished. And most importantly:

> This event is fired **every time** (in contrast to `onAfterRendering`) when the NavContainer has made this child control visible.

Since `sap.ui.core.Control` extends `sap.ui.core.Element`, every focusable control can receive the focus via `thatControl.focus()`.

---

#### Known Issues in Older UI5 Versions

- SAP Fiori launchpad (FLP) running with older SAPUI5 might take control of setting the initial focus when the app renders initially (Cf. [FLP: Setting Custom Initial Focus on App Launch Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55510704/5846045)). This issue is **no longer reproducible since SAPUI5 1.104.0**.
- In UI5 1.62 and below, calling `focus()` in `onAfterShow` alone would still make the app set the focus on the first focusable element when the user navigates back, even with `autoFocus="false"` (See this [GitHub issue #2306](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2306)). In that case, an additional `setTimeout` with **`0`** ms (or `requestAnimationFrame`) is required in order to let the browser know that the element should be focused at the end of the call stack.

  ```js
  onAfterShow: function() {
    // If UI5 version < 1.63:
    setTimeout(() => this.byId("thatControl").focus());
  },
  ```

  This issue is **no longer reproducible since UI5 1.63** (OpenUI5 [commit:`6d46cf0`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/6d46cf0b46b9660a6028a51f36f41a3086d15090)).

Answer (score 2):

The `NavContainer` has a property [autoFocus](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainer.html#getAutoFocus). `App` is a descendant of `NavContainer` so it has that property too.
The help (as linked above) states the following:

> Determines whether the initial focus is set automatically on first rendering and after navigating to a new page. This is useful when on touch devices the keyboard pops out due to the focus being automatically set on an input field. If necessary the "afterShow" event can be used to focus another element.
>
> Default value is true.

Answer (score 1):

for everyone that uses an older sapui5 version where the answer from Boghyon does not work, this here worked for me:

```js
onInit: function () {
     this.waitForAutoFocus().then(() => {
        oElementYouWantToFocus.focus();
    });
},

waitForAutoFocus: function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.hasAutoFocused(resolve);
    });
},

hasAutoFocused: function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.getCurrentFocusedControl()) {
            resolve();
        } else {
            this.hasAutoFocused(resolve);
        }
    }, 200);
},

//needs "sap/ui/core/Core" to be loaded
getCurrentFocusedControl: function () {
    const currentFocusedControlId = Core.getCurrentFocusedControlId();
    return Core.byId(currentFocusedControlId);
},
```

it basically waits for the default autofocus and then afterwards focuses your desired element

Comment: Could you share which version you were using where the existing solution was not working? Are you referring to the FLP issue in UI5 < 1.104? And in which context is the `oElementYouWantToFocus` created? Is it part of an asynchronously created fragment? Is the app generated by Fiori elements? V2? V4?

Comment: We are using Version 1.71. App was generated as basic freestyle App via vs code plugin from sap. The Element is declared in view.xml and then referred with this.byId("idOfElement")