# How to Focus on Input Field after Navigation

Tags: sapui5

How to focus on input field after navigating back from a child page?

#### Child Page

```js
onNavigateBtnClick: function() {
    var oHistory = History.getInstance();
    var sPreviousHash = oHistory.getPreviousHash();
    if (sPreviousHash !== undefined) {
        history.go(-1);
    } else {
        var bReplace = true;
        this.getRouter().navTo("HomePage", {}, bReplace);
    }
},
```

#### Parent Page

```js
onAfterRendering: function() {
    jQuery.sap.delayedCall(500, this, function() {
        this.getView().byId("InputField").focus();
    });
},
```

### Problem

1. When the nav back button is clicked first time, the `onAfterRendering` hook is called.
2. If I do some action on child page then click on the nav back button, the `onAfterRendering` method would not be called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Set Initial Focus in a View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376599/how-to-set-initial-focus-in-a-view)

Answer (score 0):

Three steps to solve this:

Update your `<App>` tag of the view to have  `autoFocus="false"`. This will prevent UI5 from autofocusing the first input of the view.

In your controller's `onInit`, attach a method to the route that will fire when the view is navigated to, like this:

```js
onInit: function(){
    var router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);

    router.getRoute("routeTargetName").attachPatternMatched(this.onNavTo, this);
}
```

Declare the `onNavTo` method in your controller that will set the focus of your input:

```js
onNavTo: function(route){
    this.byId("MyInputField").focus();
}
```

Now whenever you use your router to `navTo("routeTargetName")`, the `onNavTo` method will fire, which will set focus on the field.